# install FullCalendar via NPM to laravel project

Tags: node.js, laravel, npm, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I am still new to Laravel and web packs.

I am trying to install FullCalendar via NPM into my Laravel project - Previously I have been working with includes from cdnjs, but I want to learn the other way. What I have done so far is:
https://fullcalendar.io/docs/initialize-es6

```
npm install @fullcalendar/core @fullcalendar/daygrid @fullcalendar/timegrid @fullcalendar/list
```

Then I updates my app.js in Laravel to

```
require('./bootstrap');
require('fullcalendar');

import { Calendar }from '@fullcalendar/core';
import dayGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/daygrid';
import listPlugin from '@fullcalendar/list';
```

I also updates app.css

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

@fullcalendar/core/main.css;
@fullcalendar/daygrid/main.css;
@fullcalendar/timegrid/main.css;
@fullcalendar/list/main.css;
```

Then I ran

```
npm run dev
```

In blade file, I re-use the code from when I was working with script file from cdnjs. I added the updated app.js file, which was compiled through npm run dev

```
<div id="calendar"></div>

    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

        // page is now ready, initialize the calendar...
            var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
            var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {

                plugins: [ 'dayGrid','List'],
                header: {
                    left: 'prev,next today',
                    right: 'dayGridWeek,listWeek'
                },
                defaultView: 'dayGridWeek',
                contentHeight: 'auto',
                events : [
                        @foreach($events as $event)
                        {
                            title : '{{ $event->title }}',
                            start : '{{ $event->start_event }}',
                        },
                        @endforeach
                    ]
        });
        calendar.render();
    });
    </script>
    <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
```

The error I get is:

I don't understand why, and I have been playing around with app.js and re-compiling it a bunch of times and changing order of my code.. nothing works. What am I missing?
[image: Errors I Get]

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue, made mine work this way:

```
//app.js

...
import { Calendar } from '@fullcalendar/core';
window.Calendar = Calendar;

import interaction from '@fullcalendar/interaction';
window.interaction = interaction;

import dayGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/daygrid';
window.dayGridPlugin = dayGridPlugin;

import timeGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/timegrid';
window.timeGridPlugin = timeGridPlugin;

import listPlugin from '@fullcalendar/list';
window.listPlugin = listPlugin;
...
```

Then, I use it on pages that require me to render fullcalendar like so:

```
//somescript.js

...
var calendar = new window.Calendar($('#calendar').get(0), {
  plugins: [window.interaction, window.dayGridPlugin, window.timeGridPlugin, window.listPlugin],
  selectable: true,
  initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
  eventBorderColor: 'white',
  eventClick: info => { ... },
  dateClick: info => { ... },
  select: info => { ... }
  ...
});

calendar.render();
```

...

For styling,

```
  //app.scss

  // Variables
  @import 'variables';

  // Fullcalendar
  @fullcalendar/core/main.css;
  @fullcalendar/daygrid/main.css;
  @fullcalendar/timegrid/main.css;
  @fullcalendar/list/main.css;
```

Answer (score 1):

in Laravel 10 with Vite, this work for me, first install fullcalendar lib using npm

```
npm install @fullcalendar/core @fullcalendar/daygrid @fullcalendar/timegrid @fullcalendar/list
```

Then in app.js add this

```
import { Calendar } from '@fullcalendar/core';
import dayGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/daygrid';
import timeGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/timegrid';
import listPlugin from '@fullcalendar/list';

window.Calendar = Calendar;
window.dayGridPlugin = dayGridPlugin;
window.timeGridPlugin = timeGridPlugin;
window.listPlugin = listPlugin;
```

finally create a page like this

```
@extends('layouts.theme.app')

@section('content')
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-12">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Calendar</h5>

                    <div id='calendar'></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@endsection

@push('JS')
    <script>
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
            const calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar')
            const calendar = new Calendar(calendarEl, {
                plugins: [dayGridPlugin],
                locale: esLocale,
                headerToolbar: {
                    left: 'prev,next today',
                    center: 'title',
                    right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay,listWeek'
                }
            })
            calendar.render()
        });
    </script>
@endpush
```

Answer (score 0):

Should this line:

```
var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
```

Be changed to this:

```
var calendar = new Calendar(calendarEl, {
```

Thats what I gather from looking over https://fullcalendar.io/docs/initialize-es6

Here is a good example:
https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar-example-projects/blob/master/webpack/src/main.js

Comment: Hi, thanks for the input. Unfortuantly it is not working, its the same errors I keep getting, with the only change that now it is "Calendar is not defined" and not "FullCalendar".. But I think you are right in the change, there I also got some basics wrong somewhere

Comment: If you are using laravel and blade you can always try a wrapper like https://github.com/acaronlex/laravel-calendar

Comment: I got it to work 90% of the way using your initial idea. I wanted to use this as a learning on how to use NPM/Webpack and I think I got a better understanding, so that's great.

Now I am able to show the calendar, based on the example link. The calendar is showing, but it refreshes when I click next/prev button, or any of the other links (list, month, week view...) I can see that it quickly changes to the selected view, but then the site refreshes and I am to where I started. The console is completely blank, so I have no idea of where its going wrong.